# How to replace text in file too large for a String

Tags: java, file, replace

How can I replace text in a file that is too large for a String? I have been using the following to replace text in most of the files I've seen:

```
File f = new File("test.xml");
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(f, "UTF-8");

content = content.replaceFirst("some text", "new text");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, content, "UTF-8");
```

This works well for files that are normal sized. However, some of the files I have been getting are very large (too large to store in a String) and they cause an overflow. How can I replace text in those files?

Comment: How big is the file ??

Comment: You could try and use a buffered `Reader`, `Writer` and replace within each line while writing back to another file.

Comment: BufferedReader and BufferedWriter are the way to read/write file in Java in most of the case.

Comment: This answer details how to read files more efficiently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file?rq=1

Comment: You might be able to use a random access file, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
            File f=new File("test.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
            String content=null;

            while((content=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                content = content.replaceFirst("some text", "new text");
                System.out.println(content);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what if we got a single lined file (e.g., minified XML)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed command to replace string of large file like below [Linux]

```
String[] cmdarr = {"bash", "-c", "sed 's/oldstring/newstring/g' input.txt > output.txt"};
Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarr);
```

in Windows you can install sed, use some thing like

```
String[] cmdarr = {"cmd", "/c", "sed 's/oldstring/newstring/g' input.txt > output.txt"};
Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarr);
```

more on [Link](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42644)

Comment: I tried to run the last element of "cmdarr" on command line and it worked very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a FileInputStream to read it line-wise

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("test.xml");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
```

etc.

Sorry if there are any errors in the code, i can't try the code myself right now

Comment: replace in the while and write it in a newly generated file :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `FART`(find and replace text) 
for windows: `fart -c big_filename.txt "find_this_text" "replace_to_this"`